# Pattern for Scalable Solutions for .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, design-patterns

Which is the best pattern to work with object serialization, WCF and nhibernate + Oracle.

I mean, nhibernate is a Generic ORM tool, and i would like to make my WCF Service generic too.

Imagine that, my service has only 3 Generic Methods: "Save", "Delete", "Get" and each method has its message type.

I've tried to serialize object using JSON ... and pass it to WCF, but i've had a lot of problems with JSON Serialization (cyclic references and etc).

How do you guys implement a large-scalable-solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a data access over WCF, look into WCF Data Services. Its supports many data formats including JSON

The protocol is discussed here: http://www.odata.org/

Comment: but, this is just for http protocol ? What about net tcp  ?